# Detect two intersecting rectangles separately in opencv

Tags: opencv, shapes, detection

I can detect rectangles that are separate from each other. However, I am having problems with rectangles in contact such as below:

[Two rectangles in contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqcw7.jpg)

I should detect 2 rectangles in the image. I am using findContours as expected and I have tried various modes:CV_RETR_TREE, CV_RETR_LIST. I always get the outermost single contour as shown below:

[Outermost contour detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeSLk.jpg)

I have tried with or without canny edge detection. What I do is below:

```
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3));
cv::erode(__mat,__mat, element);
cv::dilate(__mat,__mat, element);

// Find contours
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::Mat coloredMat;
cv::cvtColor(__mat, coloredMat, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
int thresh = 100;
cv::Mat canny_output;
cv::Canny( __mat, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );

cv::findContours(canny_output, contours, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

How can I detect both two rectangles separately?

Comment: Have a look at the [watershed algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the dimensions of the rectangle, you can use [generalizedHoughTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dd4/classcv_1_1GeneralizedHough.html#gsc.tab=0)

If the dimensions of the rectangles are not known, you can use [distanceTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#distancetransform).  The local maxima will give you the center location as well as the distance from the center to the nearest edge (which will be equal to half the short side of your rect).  Further processing with corner detection / watershed and you should be able to find the orientation and dimensions (though this method may fail if the two rectangles overlap each other by a lot)

simple corner detection and brute force search (just try out all possible rectangle combinations given the corner points and see which one best matches the image, note that a rectangle can be defined given only 3 points) might also work

Comment: First, I have tried the brute-force approach: detected lines with houghlinep method and calculated angles between lines. If there are at least 3 lines intersecting each other, that should be rectangle. In theory, that should work even if rectangles are intersecting.
However, it requires a lot of checks and if and else statements and it gets just messier.


distanceTransform followed by watershed gave me the solution. I followed the example given by @Miki.